# Interchanging infinite sum and supremum

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory

We know that $$\sup\{x:x\in A\}+\sup\{y:y\in B\}=\sup\{x+y:x\in A,y\in B\}$$
But can we generalize this to infinite sum? i.e. $$\sup\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty x:x\in E_i\}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sup\{x:x\in E_i\}$$
If not, suppose $E_j$'s are disjoint?

Comment: The $\sup$ operator must be applied to a set.

Comment: It would be better to write your equation using a Cartesian product as $$\sup \Big\lbrace \sum_{i=1}^\infty  f(i) \mid f\in \large\times\normalsize_{i=1}^\infty E_i\Big\rbrace=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sup(E_i)$$  The left-hand side you have isn't really notated correctly.  (Your right-hand side is fine, but I think it's a little clearer like this.)

Answer (score 5):

If you assume that the sums make sense, e.g. if all numbers are positive, then yes (with a natural interpretation of the notation).

Let $s_i=\sup \{E_i\}\in [0,+\infty]$. We may assume $s_i<+\infty$ (or else both sides will be infinity).  Let $\epsilon>0$ and pick $x_i\in E_i$ with
 $$ s_i - \epsilon 2^{-i} \leq x_i \leq s_i$$
Then $S-\epsilon \leq \sum_i x_i \leq S$ where $S=\sum_i s_i\in [0,+\infty]$ and $\epsilon$ is arbitrary.